# Is there a way to push an object into the Ember model at a specific location?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Would like to add an object created dynamically on run-time and push it into the model. This model is used in hbs file to loop over using {{each}}.

Ideally the need is to drag an element to a sortable list and save them.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.NativeArray.html#method_insertAt